# Firebase MLkit Text recognition for digital lcd displays

Tags: android, firebase, tensorflow, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to detect the text on the digital led displays of some device like below and need help on doing that. I tried the sample for text detection that Google provides with firebase ML kit but does not perform well on device(not cloud).
Help me out on how to optimise the accuracy for on device model.
I'm looking for suggestion for doing it the right way with ML kit or are there any other alternatives that are easy than this like OpenCV, etc.

[image]

Comment: I believe ML Kit does not have an "Optimize accuracy" option, other than going for Cloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to optimise the accuracy for on device model?

Unfortunately, you cannot optimize the accuracy of the out-of-box API models in ML Kit. We will update the model to better recognize these images.

> are there any other alternatives?

Unless there is a library that performs at the level you are satisfied with, you will have to train your own model. You could potentially start with an open source model and do transfer learning for your own use case without too much data. You can look at [Tensorflow-for-poets-2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/#0) codelab for a quick tutorial on how to do this. Another option is to look at [TF Hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/) for reusing existing models easily.
Then to deploy your model onto the device for inference, please take a look at [using your own custom model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models) in ML Kit.